# Laravel eloquent relationship between two table

Tags: laravel

I have a table `notices`. Model for this table is `Notice.php`
In this table I have `notice` and `id` column.
I have fetched all notices from `notices` table and viewed in my view. Here is my controller code for fetching all notices.

```
public function index()
{
    $notice = Notice::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(5);
    return view('teacher.notice')->withNotices($notice));
}
```

Here is my view code to show all notices.

```
 @foreach($notices as $notice)
   {{$notice->id}}
   {{ $notice->notices }}
 @endforeach
```

Now I want to put two button inside this `foreach` loop. One is to `confirm` and another is `remove confirmation`. 
To store this `confirmation` data I have created another table named `notice_confirmed_student` and model for this table is `noticeConfirmedStudent.php`. In this table have three column:

```
id
student_id
notice_id
```

If a student click confirm then his id and notice id will be stored in this table. I have done this perfect. But my problem is, in the `foreach` loop it shows both two button (`confirm` and `remove confirm`) at a time. I want to show confirm button if user already not `confirmed` for this notice. If user already confirmed for that notice then it should show `remove confirmation` button.
Here I am giving my blade `foreach` loop again with button for better understanding. Bellow code is not perfect, I have just written those code to understand my question.

```
@foreach($notices as $notice)
   {{$notice->id}}
   {{ $notice->notices }}
   <?php $student_id= "select student_id from notice_confirmed_student where notice_id=$notice->id"; ?>
   @if ($student_id == $auth::user()->id)
   <button>confirm</button>
   @else
   <button>Remove Confirmation</button>
   @endif
 @endforeach
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and where are the `@if` `@else` operators to check if its confirmed or not?

Comment: Yes i am asking help for that if else condition. You can see my last part foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things are wrong/incorrect here, to make it clear,

`Notice` <> `User` relation is [`Many-Many`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) and `notice_confirmed_student` is a pivot table. so user model should have relation,

```
public function confirmedNotices()
{
     return $this->belongsToMany(Notice::class, 'notice_confirmed_student')
}
```

Then in for each loop you can check like,

```
if(in_array($notice-id, Auth::user()->confirmedNotices->pluck('id')->all())) {
     // user confirmed
} else {
    // user not confirmed.
}
```

Comment: this is the thing I was searching for. You solved my problem like a pro. Thank you so much. One more question, I have tried a lot to learn eloquent properly but I don't know why I can't learn this thing properly. Can you please give me some suggestion or tips to learn eloquent properly. I have seen a lot tutorial , read documentation from laravel.com. But still I am very weak about this.

Comment: @Fokrule You can try documentation and many blogs but end of the day nothing will be better than trial and error, just my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

if I correctly understand your issue, you need to check if record with given id exists `notice_confirmed_student` table, and then check in your loop. retrieve the confirmed students with your notices.

```
$notice = Notice::with('notice_confirmed_student_or_whatever_your_relation_method_called)')->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(5);
```

then check in loop, if related attribute is not empty like you do in your view

```
@if($notice->my_attr && $notice->my_attr->user_id == \Auth::user()->id)
   // do stuff
@else
  // it doesn't has record
@endif
```

Comment: actually what I am wanting to do is. 
       ` @foreach($notices as $notice)
       {{$notice->id}}
       {{ $notice->notices }}
       <?php $student_id= "select student_id from 
       notice_confirmed_student where notice_id=$notice->id"; ?>
       @if ($student_id == $auth::user()->id)
       <button>confirm</button>
       @else
       <button>Remove Confirmation</button>
       @endif
       @endforeach`
I have updated my question last foreach loop. can you please take a look.

Comment: so I show you how can you do it in my example. in conditions you should check if related attribute is not null and if `student_id == current_user_ud`. also its really bad thing to retrieve data from DB in loop, cause of performance, you should do it like I show you, or with `join` or whatever method you like, but not in loop. in my example there's only 1 DB call, in yours there are 6